# Java integration with SSRS

Tags: java, reporting-services, websphere

Hi I am looking into using Java (to be deployed as servlets in Websphere 8.5) to integrate with SSRS. I have looked into some of the sample codes out there and try it out.

```
private static SoapHeader createExecutionIdSoapHeader(String executionId) {     
    Document doc = DOMUtils.createDocument();

    Element executionHeaderElement = doc.createElement("ExecutionHeader");
    executionHeaderElement.setAttribute("xmlns", XML_NAMESPACE);

    Element executionIdElement = doc.createElement("ExecutionID");
    executionIdElement.setTextContent(executionId);

    executionHeaderElement.appendChild(executionIdElement);

    SoapHeader soapH = new SoapHeader(new QName(XML_NAMESPACE, "ExecutionHeader"), executionHeaderElement);     
    return soapH;
}


public static Holder<byte[]> getReportResult(String output_type, String reportFolder, String reportName, ArrayOfParameterValue arrayOfParameterValue) {
    Holder<byte[]> result = null;

    try {
        String historyID = null;
        String executionID = null;

        ReportExecutionServiceSoap service = getExecutionService();
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) service;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, authenticator.getUsername());
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, authenticator.getPassword());

        ExecutionInfo info = new ExecutionInfo();
        info = service.loadReport(REPORT_PATH, historyID);          
        executionID = info.getExecutionID();

        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
        SoapHeader header = createExecutionIdSoapHeader(executionID);

        headers.add(header);    

        bp.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

        if (!arrayOfParameterValue.getParameterValue().isEmpty()) {
            service.setExecutionParameters(arrayOfParameterValue, "en-us");
        }

        // Default to return HTML4.0
        String deviceInfo = "";
        if (output_type == null || output_type.isEmpty()) {
            output_type = "HTML4.0";
        }

        if ("IMAGE".equalsIgnoreCase(output_type)) {
            deviceInfo = RENDER_DEVICE_INFO_IMAGE;
        } else {
            deviceInfo = RENDER_DEVICE_INFO_HTML;
        }

        result = new Holder<byte[]>();
        Holder<String> extension = new Holder<String>();
        Holder<String> mimeType = new Holder<String>();
        Holder<String> encoding = new Holder<String>();
        Holder<ArrayOfWarning> warnings = new Holder<ArrayOfWarning>();
        Holder<ArrayOfString> streamIDs = new Holder<ArrayOfString>();

        service.render(output_type, deviceInfo, result, extension, mimeType, encoding, warnings, streamIDs);
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ArrayOfParameterValue arrayOfParameterValue = new ArrayOfParameterValue();
        List<ParameterValue> parameters = arrayOfParameterValue.getParameterValue();
        ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
        parameterValue.setName(PARAMETER_NAME);
        parameterValue.setValue(PARAMETER_VALUE);
        parameters.add(parameterValue);

        Holder<byte[]> result = GenerateReport.getReportResult(REPORT_FORMAT, REPORT_FOLDER, REPORT_NAME,
                arrayOfParameterValue);

        System.out.println("--------------------------------- Writing to Browser --------------------------------");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(result.value);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("--------------------------------- Writing to File -----------------------------------");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss_");
        Date date = new Date();
        String filename = df.format(date) + "SSRS_Report.pdf";
        FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\keh\\Desktop\\Temp\\" + filename);
        o.write(result.value);
        o.flush();
        o.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the codes, I have this error :

[5/17/17 19:21:02:704 SGT] 000000c4 SystemErr     R javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation.  ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.MissingSessionIdException: The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required for this operation.

Any expert out there can point me to a solution pls?

P.S. I have tried to use WSBindingProvider as shown in Surendra Gurjar's Blog and it ran beautifully on an Apache server, but I got a ClassCastException when I deploy it to Websphere.